# All images are stretched to take the full width of the page and cannot be resized

Tags: image

I have a weird problem in all my 'news pages" of our SharePoint 2013 Internet portal. Whenever I place an image in the "Roll-up image" section, It's taking the whole width of the page automatically, and  CAN NOT be resized.

I have tried so many things, like adding the predefined and custom image renditions to the image path, and also to delete them and apply the rendition again with custom ones, but with no luck. Same goes for removing the "lock aspect ratio" and entering the width manually.... Every time I do these changes and apply, it's reverting back to the distorted image which takes the whole width of the page.

Please I need your feedback urgently; as we've more than 15 pages with about 75 news ads (all of them have the same issue).

Thanks in advance,

Ali

Comment: Did you enabled the blob cache in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 On-Premise image renditions are not enabled OOB. We need to set the blob cache of a web application to `true`

1. Goto the virtual directory of your web application
2. open the web.config file, and find `BlobCache` attribute.
3. Set enabled="true"
4. Reset the IIS

After above steps, image renditions should work normally like we see in SharePoint Online